# Try to use struct with more then 1 parameter, gets ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, struct

This is the first time I use struct. I try to build a char program in python.
This is working fine:

```
s = struct.pack("!I", 4) + "hello"
(i,), data = struct.unpack("!I", s[:4]), s[4:]
```

but when I try with more than 1 parameter I get a ValueError: too many values to unpack when i try to unpack it. Like in this code:

```
s = struct.pack("!III", 4, 4, 4) + "hello"
(i,), data = struct.unpack("!III", s[:12]), s[12:]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You only want to obtain the first parameter?

Comment: try this `(i,j,k), data = struct.unpack("!III", s[:12]), s[12:]`

Comment: Thanks you! I didnt noticed that I ignored the other parameters :(